# Navmesh agent stops working when there are too many agents

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have an enemy navmeshagent which once the conditions for retreating have been met, calls StartRetreating()

```
public void StartRetreating()
    {
        animator.SetBool("Attack", false);
        isRetreating = true;
        StartCoroutine(Retreat());
    }
```

The next bit of coding is as follows:

```
private Vector3 GetRandomPointAroundPlayer(Vector3 center, float radius)
    {
        Vector3 randomDirection = Random.insideUnitSphere * radius;
        randomDirection.y = 0f;
        Vector3 randomPoint = center + randomDirection;

        NavMeshHit hit;
    if (NavMesh.SamplePosition(randomPoint, out hit, radius, NavMesh.AllAreas))
    {
        return hit.position;
    }

    // If no valid position is found, return the original center position
    return center;
}

IEnumerator Retreat()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    animator.SetBool("Walk", false);
    wanderTarget = GetRandomPointAroundPlayer(enemySight.player.transform.position, wanderRadius);
    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(wanderTarget, 3f); // Adjust the radius as needed
    foreach (Collider collider in colliders)
    {
        if (collider.CompareTag("RetreatPoint"))
        {
            // Retreat point found nearby, get a new random target
            wanderTarget = GetRandomPointAroundPlayer(enemySight.player.transform.position, wanderRadius);
        }
    }
    Walk(wanderTarget);
}

void Walk(Vector3 wanderTarget)
{
    if (canSpawnRetreatPoint)
    {
        retreatObject=Instantiate(retreatPoint, new(wanderTarget.x, -2, wanderTarget.z), Quaternion.identity);
        canSpawnRetreatPoint = false;
    }
    if (enemySight.playerOnRight == true && enemyWalk.facingRight == true)
    {
        enemyWalk.Flip();
    }
    else if (enemySight.playerOnRight == false && !enemyWalk.facingRight)
    {
        enemyWalk.Flip();
    }
    navMeshAgent.speed = enemyWalk.enemySpeed; //Assign the enemy speed to the navmesh speed
    enemyWalk.enemyCurrentSpeed = navMeshAgent.velocity.sqrMagnitude;
    navMeshAgent.SetDestination(wanderTarget); // Move to the player's location
    navMeshAgent.updateRotation = false; //prevent the enemy sprite from rotating
   

}
```

This works fine when there is only one or two agents, but when you add 4 agents, atleast one of the agents usually get stuck in a walk or retreat state. The walk animation plays, but the agent is stuck like this:

[image]

The retreat points each have a trigger that increments and allows the agent to complete it's retreat cycle. When I drag the agents to the retreat point, the trigger works correctly and it switches to its Walk state(where it's supposed to walk towards the player). But it still doesn't move and is still like this:

[image]

In both cases, the navmesh agent is active and knows where to move, but doesn't move. Once I manually drag the agent to the player's attack point in the editor, the agent starts attacking again and resumes operating as intended.

I also get the following error when I load up the scene:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.Graphs.Edge.WakeUp () (at <871096295abe423b9c0af38ec6fe4bf2>:0)
UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.DoWakeUpEdges (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] inEdges, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] ok, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] error, System.Boolean inEdgesUsedToBeValid) (at <871096295abe423b9c0af38ec6fe4bf2>:0)
UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.WakeUpEdges (System.Boolean clearSlotEdges) (at <871096295abe423b9c0af38ec6fe4bf2>:0)
UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.WakeUp (System.Boolean force) (at <871096295abe423b9c0af38ec6fe4bf2>:0)
UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.WakeUp () (at <871096295abe423b9c0af38ec6fe4bf2>:0)
UnityEditor.Graphs.Graph.OnEnable () (at <871096295abe423b9c0af38ec6fe4bf2>:0)
```

Comment: 4 agents is definately not on the realm of "too many"  I seem to recall I tried like 400 at one point.. it wasnt maybe performant but it still worked.  Id suggest a lot more debugging is needed

Comment: I figured it out! I was setting the navmeshagent.IsStopped to true and not setting it back properly.